# Duplicate symbol_main

Tags: c++, xcode

I've been looking for solutions for this problem but them didn't work for me! I've been having a lot of problems compiling programs. 
When I'm trying to execute a program in Xcode appears:

> duplicate symbol _main in /Users/LauraChaparro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Busqueda-ercduihvfosqcoczkrgljkkmgxam/Build/Intermediates/Busqueda.build/Debug/Busqueda.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Uno.o and /Users/LauraChaparro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Busqueda-ercduihvfosqcoczkrgljkkmgxam/Build/Intermediates/Busqueda.build/Debug/Busqueda.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o for architecture x86_64

I don't understand why this happens! Is a C++ project... Or if you can recommend me another IDE I'll be really thankful!

Comment: I once copied another widget into another widget. So I had two `@main`. Hence this error message

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you are defining a `main` in some of the code used to make the `Uno.o` object file. You can only have one `main`, so objects used to build libraries should not define a `main`. This should only be defined in the application itself.

This a linker error and it likely you would encounter it with other IDEs. You need to find where in `Uno.o` the `main` is defined and remove it.

Comment: Thanks... Finally I can run it!

Answer (score 3):

The error you have there is a **linker error**. It tells you exactly what is wrong. The linker has found out that it can find the symbol *_main* defined more than one time looking through the object files. This makes it impossible for the linker to create an executable of your object files, as it have no way of telling which symbol you want to use. It continues to tell you where it found the two symbols.

Once in the Uno.o file (which I will assume come from compiling the Uno.cpp file)
another from the main.o file (from the main.cpp file)

This means, that somehow the linker can find the symbol for the main method in both files.

This could happen by:

- Defining a **main** function *both in* the Uno.cpp and main.cpp
- Having placed a *non inline* **main** definition in a header and including this both in the Uno.cpp file and the main.cpp file (or an include that includes another include and so on.)

As your request for another IDE I would like to remind you that neither compiler errors or linker errors are errors in the IDE, in an overwhelming number of cases the problem is that the user of the IDE has done something wrong.

Comment: Great! Learning to read the errors from the compiler and the linker are an important skill to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once, Make sure you include your .h file instead of your .c file in the file you don't expect your main function to be. I had my include statement having .c file and it produced the same issue .